# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is not a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Q}[y_1,\dots,y_n]$ for any $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to show that the field of rational functions $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is not a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Q}[y_1,\dots,y_n]$ for any $n$?

I thought proving this by contradiction. So suppose for some $n$, $f: \mathbb{Q}[y_1,\dots,y_n]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(x)$ is a surjective homomorphism. Then $\mathbb{Q}[y_1,\dots,y_n]/\ker(f)\cong \mathbb{Q}(x)$.
Does this argument lead to a solution?

Comment: Perhaps you can share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

There are infinitely many prime polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Finitely many rational functions will only generate rational functions with powers of finitely many primes in the denominator. Thus the image of $\mathbb{Q}[y_1, \ldots y_n]$ will be a proper subfield.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\mathbb Q(x)\simeq\mathbb Q[y_1,\dots,y_n]/\mathfrak m$, where $\mathfrak m$ is necessarily a maximal ideal. Then $A=\mathbb Q[y_1,\dots,y_n]/\mathfrak m$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Q$-algebra (actually a field), and by [Zariski's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski's_lemma) $A$ is a finite field extension of $\mathbb Q$. On the other side, $x$ is transcendental over $\mathbb Q$, and we obtained a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Starting from where you left off: finitely generated $\Bbb Q$ algebras are exactly the rings $A$ such that there exists a surjective ring homomorphism $\Bbb Q[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]\to A$.

Is $\Bbb Q(x)$ a finitely generated algebra?

Comment: The fact about finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}$ algebras, how can it be proved?
No $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is not a finitely generated algebra so the result follows.

Comment: Dear @rschwieb, I think your hint is in fact a reformulation of the question and nothing more. Maybe you want to add some details.

Comment: @user26857 No, that is a bad idea. It would no longer be a hint. Perhaps you have not observed that many of the best hints are just "reformulations" from which the student suddenly sees the answer. I was betting the student is familiar with the basic fact I ended with, and could complete the argument him/herself. Regards.

Comment: @Test123 It's clear how to prove the lemma about finitely generated $\Bbb Q$ algebras, right? Just choose a set of generators of the algebra, and then map different variables to the generators. The mapping property of the polynomial ring makes a ring homomorphism.

Comment: My main concern is that the last sentence of your answer isn't trivial at all, and that one maybe deserved a hint.

Comment: @rschwieb I knew the result that $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is not a finitely generated algebra but didn't know that finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}$ algebras are exactly the rings $A$ such that there exists a surjective ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2,…,x_n]\rightarrow A$. But to be honest I am not familiar with a proof that $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is not a finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}$ algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If $\;x\;$ is algebraic over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ and $\;y\;$ is trascendental, then we certainly have that

$$\Bbb Q(x)\cong \Bbb Q[y]/\langle\,f(y)\,\rangle$$

with $\;f(y)\in\Bbb Q[y]\;$ the minimal polynomial of $\;x\;$ over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ .

So you have to give some conditions on $\;x,y_1,...\;$ for your claim to be true.